# Contour Plot using 2D set of data

Tags: c#, graphics, contour

I've got an XY coordinate set of data, and I need to be able to create a contour plot from that data. Is there an existing C# library that will provide me with this functionality?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [interpolation](http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Interpolation&referringTitle=Documentation) on the [Math.NET Numerics](http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex.

The project:

> Numerics is the numerical foundation of the Math.NET project, aiming
>   to provide methods and algorithms for numerical computations in
>   science, engineering and every day use. Covered topics include special
>   functions, linear algebra, probability models, random numbers,
>   interpolation, integral transforms and more.

There are also a number of [sample methods](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Advanced-Graphics/DrawYourOwnContourFunction.htm) on java2s.com. Yup, it's Java but Math is pretty easy to port to C#.